# Positioning menu with percentages instead of pixel

Tags: html, css

```
.navigation
{ 
float:right;
margin:0 auto;
}
ul.menu 
{
margin:0 0 0 0;
 padding:0;
 position:relative;
 top:75px;
 list-style:none;}

 //CSS
```

And this is the div my menu is in:

`<div id="topMenuDiv" style="background-color:gray;height:20%;width:99%;margin: 0 0 -2px 0;position: absolute;top:0px;border: 1px solid red;">`

```
<div class="navigation"><ul class="menu">
```

This is what comes after topMenuDiv(I'm sorry if I'm still not specific)

How could I position my menu relative to the div in percentages and not pixels?(I left out the ul and li part of the menu).If anyone would please help me on this , I would really appreciate it ...Thanks.

Comment: uhm, maybe use top: value%; ? and somethings wrong here: you first show some css, and then some markup not related with any css above -_- , try to give more details, a jsfiddle or a code snippet goes a long way

Comment: i've tried using top:value% but it justs puts my menu on the top of  the div it is in,no matter what % i use.

Comment: well thats whats expected when you use position absolute, you use top, left, bottom, right props. to position it inside its container(or some parent with relative position); try setting a height value for its parent, else if the parent has no other children it will collapse

Comment: it works if I change to absolute and then position it with top:value% and left:value% ,but when I change the screen resolution,the menu is not where it should be.(the initial reason i wanted to change it to percentage was to adjust my site to all screen resolutions).

Comment: it should stay the same for top/left and a given width/height, however consider that when youll resize, top/left will grow/shrink with the changed width/height

Answer (score 0):

If the position of your menu be `relative`it's an unusual work to define `top`, `left` or .... . It's better to position it as `absolute` and you can define `top`, `left` or .... easily with percentages.

Comment: If I change it to absolute, my menu will go on the right side of the screen and change from horizontal to vertical

Comment: you say it is placed in a div which is positioned with `absolute` . so nothing should be wrong and your menu should be in your div. check it first , then if it didn't work change the position of your div to relative that menu be in that.

Comment: yes.my menu is placed in a div with absolute...but now i see that the div the menu is placed in ,is also placed in another bigger div also with absolute so..maybe that's the problem?

Comment: in the default situation each with positioned with `absolute` will define screen to be it's frame . but, if it be in another div , use can position your main div to `absolute` or `relative` and then the frame of your sub div to define top or left and ... will be the main div. if the bigger div is positioned to `relative` or `absolute` no problem will make.